# Magento 2 Salable Quantity did not set when create product or edit product

Tags: magento2, quantity, catalog-product

I have created one Product and when I save this Product or else Edit this Product, the **Salable Quantity** is not set.

You can get references using the below image.

**https://i.imgur.com/osAZIqc.png**

**https://i.imgur.com/jUdKkqq.png**

How to fix this Issue?

Answer (score 1):

First Take a Backup of the 'inventory_source_item' Table.

Then run the below query in the database.

```
INSERT INTO `inventory_source_stock_link` (`link_id`, `stock_id`, `source_code`, `priority`) VALUES ('1', '1', 'default', '1');
```

After then Run Below Command.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the two solution for this which can help you to resolve this issue

1. Run the indexer command

   `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

After that check whether your salable quantity is updated or not.

2. If the above method does not work then run the below query in MySQL db

   UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_status SET stock_status = 1

Some stock status is not set in db try to set the value in db.